# Python: save attachments from .msg files

Tags: python, email, pdf, extract

So I have a folder with a ton of .msg files. I want to be able to save one of the attachments. My idea was automating clicking the files, then somehow extracting the file with a certain file name but I have yet to find any solutions to this.

How do I go about doing this? Or a better way?

Thanks!

Update:
I've got an idea to use os.startfile to open the file I want it to open...
How do I not open it in another window? But act like it did? If that makes any sense :/

Comment: This question may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937664/how-to-extract-attachments-from-msg-files

Comment: I saw this file! Unfortunately, I already have the msg file in a folder. So it isn't directly interacting with outlook

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filename)        #filename including path
att=msg.Attachments
for i in att:
    i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(Pathname, i.FileName))#Saves the file with the attachment name
```

Since you say you have a folder, this will automate the whole folder:

```
import win32com.client
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".msg"):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)        
        att=msg.Attachments
        for i in att:
            i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(Pathname, i.FileName))#Saves the file with the attachment name
```

Comment: can we close the file? I get this error: ""We can't open 'HVB Curves 27-1-2021.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission"

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097717/opening-files-with-spaces-with-outlook-openshareditem-is-giving-error

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Harish answer because, for me, the method didn't work, as OpenSharedItem() requires an absolute path.

As such I recommend the following for an entire folder:

```
import win32com.client
import os
inputFolder = r'.' ## Change here the input folder
outputFolder = r'.' ## Change here the attachments output folder

for file in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    if file.endswith(".msg"):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        filePath = inputFolder  + '\\' + file
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filePath)
        att = msg.Attachments
        for i in att:
            i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputFolder, i.FileName))#Saves the file with the attachment name
```

Comment: This is great, one step closer to solving the problem I'm facing. The issue I have is that msg files are scattered in different directories within the drive. I have listed all the relevant files in a pandas df column. Is there a solution where I can loop through different directories rather than providing absolute path?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem but Python comes with  [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html). This will at least help you read the msg file (assuming it's in proper format)

```
import email
with open('/path/to/your/file.msg') as fl:
    msg = email.message_from_file(fl)
```

That will give you a [Message](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) object. You should be able to get the file using `msg.walk()` which will give you all the attached content.

```
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "image/png":
        with open('out.png', 'w') as fl:
            fl.write(part.get_payload(decode=True)))
```